# Best practices to trigger a Firebase Cloud Function just once

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I need to trigger a Firebase Cloud Function just once every time a new Firebase Auth user is created. I already wrote a fully working function that sends one email per user using the onCreate trigger. 
The function sends a welcome email and track some analytics data, so it is not idempotent.

The problem here is that Google arbitrarily calls that function multiple times. This is not a "bug" but an expected behaviour and the dev must handle it.

I want to know what is the best practice to change the "at least once" behaviour to the "exactly once" one.

What happens now:

1. New User "A" signs up.
2. Google fires the "sendWelcomeEmail" for the user A.
3. Google fires the "sendWelcomeEmail" for the user A *AGAIN*.

What is the best way to run the function just once and abort/skip any other invocation for the same user?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#trigger_a_function_on_user_creation

Comment: You need just when the first user is created or everytime a user is created?

Comment: The function must be invoked once everytime a new user is created.

Comment: But Firebase already has a built-in function for sending such an email, doesn't it...? As a work-around in this specific case, why not just use that, and customize the email sent?! :)

Comment: @KarolinaHagegård  "at least once" doesn't mean "exactly once". Google randomly sends multiple emails because the function is not idempotent.

Comment: @Antonio, I know the difference between "at least" and "exactly"! What I don't understand is your point? In OP, you talk about an `onCreate` function. I talk about the built-in Firebase email function that you activate through the Firebase console. I'm sure that one sends exactly one email per new user!...

Comment: @KarolinaHagegård I wasn't interested in customizing the "Email address verification" email template. I wanted to send custom emails triggered by specific events (e.g. onUserCreate). Furthermore, I had to call external API services exactly once.

Comment: I know. That's why I called it "a work-around"...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I faced a similar problem and there's no easy solution. I found that for any action that is using an external system it's quite impossible to make such a function idempotent. I'm using TypeScript and Firestore.

For a solution to this problem, you will need to use [Firebase transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions). Only using transaction you'll be able to face race conditions which happen when a function is triggered multiple times, usually at the same time.

I found that there are 2 levels of this problem:

1. You don't have an idempotent function, you just need sending email to be idempotent.
2. You have a set of idempotent functions and need to execute some actions that require integration with external systems.

Examples of such integration are:

- sending an email
- connecting to a payment system

---

## 1. For non-idempotent function (simple case scenario)

```
async function isFirstRun(user: UserRecord) {
  return await admin.firestore().runTransaction(async transaction => {
    const userReference = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(user.uid);

    const userData = await transaction.get(userReference) as any
    const emailSent = userData && userData.emailSent
    if (!emailSent) {
      transaction.set(userReference, { emailSent: true }, { merge: true })
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  })
}

export const onUserCreated = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user, context) => {
  const shouldSendEmail = await isFirstRun(user);
  if (shouldSendEmail) {
    await sendWelcomeEmail(user)
  }
})
```

P.S. You can also use built-in `eventId` field to filter out duplicated event fires. See https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-functions-pro-tips-building-idempotent-functions. The work required will be comparable – you still have to store already processed actions or events.

---

## 2. For a set of already idempotent functions (real case scenario)

To make this work with a set of functions that are already idempotent I switched to the queuing system. I push actions to the collection and utilize Firebase Transactions to "lock" execution of the action to only one function at a time.

I'll try to put the minimal example here.

Deploy the action handler function

```
export const onActionAdded = functions.firestore
  .document('actions/{actionId}')
  .onCreate(async (actionSnapshot) => {
    const actionItem: ActionQueueItem = tryPickingNewAction(actionSnapshot)

    if (actionItem) {
      if (actionItem.type === "SEND_EMAIL") {
        await handleSendEmail(actionItem)
        await actionSnapshot.ref.update({ status: ActionQueueItemStatus.Finished } as ActionQueueItemStatusUpdate)
      } else {
        await handleOtherAction(actionItem)
      }
    }
  });

/** Returns the action if no other Function already started processing it */
function tryPickingNewAction(actionSnapshot: DocumentSnapshot): Promise<ActionQueueItem> {
  return admin.firestore().runTransaction(async transaction => {
    const actionItemSnapshot = await transaction.get(actionSnapshot.ref);
    const freshActionItem = actionItemSnapshot.data() as ActionQueueItem;

    if (freshActionItem.status === ActionQueueItemStatus.Todo) {
      // Take this action
      transaction.update(actionSnapshot.ref, { status: ActionQueueItemStatus.Processing } as ActionQueueItemStatusUpdate)
      return freshActionItem;
    } else {
      console.warn("Trying to process an item that is already being processed by other thread.");
      return null;
    }
  })
}
```

Push actions to the collection like this

```
admin.firestore()
    .collection('actions')
    .add({
      created: new Date(),
      status: ActionQueueItemStatus.Todo,
      type: 'SEND_EMAIL',
      data: {...}
    })
```

TypeScript definitions

```
export enum ActionQueueItemStatus {
  Todo = "NEW",
  Processing = "PROCESSING",
  Finished = "FINISHED"
}

export interface ActionQueueItem {
  created: Date
  status: ActionQueueItemStatus
  type: 'SEND_EMAIL' | 'OTHER_ACTION'
  data: EmailActionData
}

export interface EmailActionData {
  subject: string,
  content: string,
  userEmail: string,
  userDisplayName: string
}
```

You may need to adjust this with richer statuses and their changes, but this approach should work for any case and the code provided should a good starting point. This also doesn't include a mechanism to rerun failed actions, but they are easy to find.

If you know a simpler way of doing this - please tell me how :)

Good luck!

Comment: Implementing a Task queue was our solution.

Comment: Thanks for the info. What I realized now is that for sending a welcome email, even when using the task queue you need to make sure that adding to the queue is idempotent too, and sending is idempotent. So you still need to do some check whether a welcome email to this person was sent/scheduled or not. So de facto mixing both or solutions from my answer.

How do you do this? I imagine we need to only add to the queue when a welcome email for this user is not present or use some sort of flag - both in a transaction.

Comment: Facing the same issue here. Quite a pain in the ass to deal with this behaviour. As long as a third party is involved, you can't rely on firebase...

Comment: I wouldn't say you can't, but it's painful. In my case, I use this queue of actions, and I then monitor actions that have failed with an option to rerun them. This keeps flaky actions out of the main transactional system.

Comment: You can use the event ID to identify multiple calls to the same function. See https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-functions-pro-tips-building-idempotent-functions

Comment: @damienix Will this event queue technique scale well? I mean, does it work well with tons of collections, listeners, and triggers firing together, all adding to the same collection? And then do you have all your triggers adding to the same event queue, and then the one event queue listener that delegates what happens thereafter, so essentially its one trigger that does all the hard work?

Comment: Hey, TBH I don't know but I can guess :) My scale was not big, maybe pushing up to a few hundred events/emails at a time. I did manual re-tries after inspecting them, but this can be automated for common errors.

Firebase Functions has practically unlimited autoscaling in the matter seconds. Triggers fire in parallel. Regarding concurrent transactions, transaction fails only when a document fetched in the transaction has been modified by another thread. As each action executor (exception of rare duplicated events) reads one document, to my understanding this will scale very well too.

Comment: Hi. This is a great answer! But could you plz complete the code sections with stuff that needs to be `required` or `imported` for the code to run? I'm very new to Cloud Functions and I don't know where to find `transaction` etc.

Comment: Well, the only missing pieces are `firebase` and `admin` well known names used by official SDKs, https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup and https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started. The `transaction` is a param of passed function so it's not missing. Is there anything else that's missing?