# Firebase Cloud Functions execution results for Firestore writes differ from actual observed values

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am using `Cloud-Functions` to keep track of how many users are currently authenticated (to get the *actual user count*).

These are my functions:

```
exports.accountCreate = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
    console.log(user.uid);
    const userCounterRef = admin.firestore().collection("data").doc("userCounter");

    return userCounterRef.update({
        userCounter: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
    });
});

exports.accountDelete = functions.auth.user().onDelete((user) => {
    console.log(user.uid);
    const userCounterRef = admin.firestore().collection("data").doc("userCounter");

    return userCounterRef.update({
        userCounter: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1),
    });
});
```

I tested it and it seemed to work correctly, but after a while the `userCounter` differs from the value I am seeing in my Firebase Dashboard.

How can that be? I have absolutely no idea. Any help is appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Instead of counting documents like this, do you know that you can simply use a [count aggregation query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries#use_the_count_aggregation), assuming that you are just trying to find the number of documents in a collection?  If you just create a document for each user, and continually make sure that it exists for each user as they use the app, you can just count the number of documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Functions does not guarantee exactly-once execution of triggers because of the way distributed computing systems work, especially with respect to possible errors that can't be eliminated from the system.  At best, it can guarantee at-least-once execution.  This is discussed in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/retries):

> Cloud Functions guarantees at-least-once execution of an event-driven function for each event emitted by an event source. By default, if a function invocation terminates with an error, the function is not invoked again and the event is dropped. When you enable retries on an event-driven function, Cloud Functions retries a failed function invocation until it completes successfully or the retry window expires.

All that is to say, Cloud Functions might retry your function some number of times if it's not certain that it was completed on the first try. It's up to you to write code to make sure that your functions are idempotent with respect to retries built into the system.

See also: [Best practices to trigger a Firebase Cloud Function just once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52558944/best-practices-to-trigger-a-firebase-cloud-function-just-once)